# Unable to connect to Aws SQS using localstack module of test container

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, testcontainers, localstack

I am trying to set up environment for integration test, so far i have used postgrsql module of test container and was able to make it work but localstack is throwing the below exception when i run tests.

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [com.hardik.killchamber.service.PersonService personService] in constructor [public com.hardik.killchamber.test.LocalstackSpringBootPocApplicationTests(com.hardik.killchamber.service.PersonService)]: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:239)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:183)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.NestedClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(NestedClassTestDescriptor.java:85)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(SpringExtension.java:283)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:216)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 609a8137-add4-5c69-a298-d986cc31ef35)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 609a8137-add4-5c69-a298-d986cc31ef35)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1660)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2147)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2116)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2105)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeGetQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:1138)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:1110)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.buffered.AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient.java:260)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.support.destination.DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.java:94)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.support.destination.DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DynamicQueueUrlDestinationResolver.java:38)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.CachingDestinationResolverProxy.resolveDestination(CachingDestinationResolverProxy.java:92)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.queueAttributes(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.initialize(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:293)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:111)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:268)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.afterPropertiesSet(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 89 more
```

Here is the Localstack container code in which i have a static container variable and i am initializing and starting the contiainer in the static block and all the test classes in which i test the aws services will extend the below class

```
@Testcontainers
public class AmazonWebServiceTestContainer {

    public final static LocalStackContainer container;

    public final static String bucketName;

    public final static String topicArn;

    public final static String queueName;
    
    private final static AmazonSNSClient amazonSnsClient;
    
    private final static AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync; 
    
    private final static AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    static {
        container = new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:0.11.3")).withServices(S3, SNS,
                SQS);

        if (!(container.isCreated() && container.isRunning()))
            container.start();

        // MAKE S3 Bucket
        amazonS3 =  AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(container.getEndpointConfiguration(S3))
                .withCredentials(container.getDefaultCredentialsProvider()).build();
        bucketName = amazonS3
                .createBucket(RandomString.make(8).toLowerCase()).getName();

        // INIT SNS CLIENT
        amazonSnsClient = (AmazonSNSClient)AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(container.getEndpointConfiguration(SNS))
                .withCredentials(container.getDefaultCredentialsProvider()).build();

        // CREATE SNS TOPIC
        topicArn = amazonSnsClient.createTopic(RandomString.make(7)).getTopicArn();

        // STATIC QUEUE NAME TO MATCH @SqsListener CODE
        queueName = "killchamber-queue";

        // INIT SQS CLIENT
        amazonSQSAsync = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(container.getRegion())
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicAWSCredentials(container.getAccessKey(), container.getSecretKey())))
        .build();
        
        amazonSQSAsync.createQueue(queueName);

        // SUBSCRIBE SQS TO SNS TOPIC
        //SubscribeRequest request = new SubscribeRequest(topicArn, "sqs", null);
        //amazonSnsClient.subscribe(request);

    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Profile("testing")
    public AmazonSNSClient getSnsClient() {
        return amazonSnsClient;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Profile("testing")
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {
        return amazonSQSAsync;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("testing")
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
        return amazonS3;
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("cloud.aws.region.static", container::getRegion);

        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.storage.access-key", container::getAccessKey);
        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.storage.secret-key", container::getSecretKey);
        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.storage.region", container::getRegion);
        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.storage.bucket-name", () -> bucketName);

        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.sns.properties.access-key", container::getAccessKey);
        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.sns.properties.secret-key", container::getSecretKey);
        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.sns.properties.topic-arn", () -> topicArn);

        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.sqs.properties.access-key", container::getAccessKey);
        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.sqs.properties.secret-key", container::getSecretKey);
        registry.add("com.hardik.killchamber.sqs.properties.queue-name", () -> queueName);
    }

}
```

I only have on test class right now, because it's throwing the above error

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class LocalstackSpringBootPocApplicationTests extends PostgresqlTestContainer{
    
    private final  PersonService personService;
    
    @Autowired
    public LocalstackSpringBootPocApplicationTests(PersonService personService) {
        super();
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @Nested
    public class Demo extends AmazonWebServiceTestContainer{

        @Test
        void contextLoads() {
            MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("abc.png", "HARDIK SINGH BEHL".getBytes());
            personService.create("{\"email\":\"behlHardik@gmail.com\",\"fullName\":\"behlHardik\",\"age\":28}", file);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the github repository of the code
https://github.com/hardikSinghBehl/localstack-spring-boot

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of your error is that `@SpringBootTest` can't see your custom spring beans defined in `AmazonWebServiceTestContainer` class (like `amazonSQSAsync`) and uses the ones provided by spring-cloud-aws.
So essentially your test is trying to use real AWS, not localstack.

To make localstack-aware beans visible they should be defined in a class annotated with `@Configuration` or `@TestConfiguration`. Mark `AmazonWebServiceTestContainer` with one of them as a quick fix.
If you prefer the second annotation (`@TestConfiguration`) you also need to import it:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(AmazonWebServiceTestContainer.class)
class LocalstackSpringBootPocApplicationTests extends PostgresqlTestContainer
```

A cleaner long team solution would be to extract the beans into a separate class like `LocalAwsConfiguration`.

Comment: The section Spring Cloud AWS < 2.3.0 Integration Test Setup can also be used to understand above.https://rieckpil.de/test-spring-applications-using-aws-with-testcontainers-and-localstack/